# Check to see if a Configuration is Possible: prove there's an Hamiltonian path on a connected subset of the square grid graph

Tags: mathematics, geometry, solvability, computer-science

> Alright, here's a new one for you guys. Instead of solving it, you need to determine if **any given configuration** is possible to solve, without actually solving it. *It needs to be a general method of figuring it out, and should apply to most (if not all) situations.*

Without further ado, here's the puzzle you have to use:

Imagine a square grid of arbitrary size.  Now picture a T-shape drawn on it; the T is 3 blocks wide and 5 blocks tall as seen in the image below left.

Now picture starting on the top left, and staying within the T shape/boundaries, slowly progressing, filling each square as you go. Can you fill in all the squares of the grid? ***Of course not!*** The most you can do us fill 6 squares!

**However if the shape itself was a square (like the shape below right), you can fill the entire shape.**

[image: T and square shapes on a grid]

**How to move:** *Move to any orthogonally adjacent square which you have not already visited in the shape.*

***Note:*** For all situations you may assume to start in the upper left corner. Accepted answer goes to the simplest method.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130425/hamiltonian-path-detection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you seem to be asking (assuming the squares are completely filled), is to find an [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) on a connected subset of the [square grid graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph).

Defintions (lifted from Wikipedia)

> A **Hamiltonian path** (or traceable path) is a path in an undirected or directed graph that visits each vertex exactly once.
>
> A **square grid graph** is the graph whose vertices correspond to the points in the plane with integer coordinates, x-coordinates being in the range 1,..., n, y-coordinates being in the range 1,..., m, and two vertices are connected by an edge whenever the corresponding points are at distance 1.

As far as I can tell, the answer is that the [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is an NP-complete problem, which means that there is no polynomial time algorithm to determine if an arbitrary graph contains a Hamiltonian path.  In other words, **given a large enough shape, it might take nearly forever just to find out if there is a solution to the stated problem.**

---

A simple heuristic can determine if there is no solution: If a square is connected to only one other square (i.e. it has a degree of 1), it must either be the first or last square visited, since you can't backtrack. Hence, any shape with more than 2 such squares (marked with "1" in the image below) has no solution.

*However, the converse is not true*. The shape below right has 2 squares with degree 1, but is unsolvable as well.

[image: vertex degrees added]

---

Another heuristic (courtesy of Lopsy): color the squares like a checkerboard. The number of white and black squares can only differ by 1 if it is solvable. If e.g. there is one more white square than black, then the path must start and end on white.

In this case the T shape satisfies the heuristic while the shape on the right does not.  Both are not solvable which again shows that the converse is false.

[image: checkerboard]

---

You can also simplify shapes by removing a vertex of degree 1 if and only if it is connected to a vertex of degree 2.  For example, the following shapes are equivalent in terms of their solvability:

[image: equivalent T shapes]

---

Lets put what we have learned to use.  Here is a complex shape which satisfies both heuristics (only 1 vertex of degree 1, and there are 7 black squares vs 6 light squares).  But we can remove the vertex with degree 1 because it is connected to a vertex of degree 2, and now the new shape does not satisfy the checkerboard heuristic anymore.  So, the shape has no hamiltonian path.

[image: Complex shape]

---

This is really a question more for math or computer science: 
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamiltonian-paths 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/hamiltonian-paths

This may also be of interest (algorithms for finding Hamiltonian paths for L, C, F, and E shaped graphs on a grid): http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2012/475087/

Comment: I don't want to solve it, I want to be able to tell if **it can be solved or not.**

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I have edited the answer to reflect that more clearly.  My answer is still the same though.

Comment: Could you share some tips on going about figuring it out? For example the T example shape won't work, could you explain some tell tale signs?

Comment: If a square is connected to only one other square, it must either be the first or last square visited, since you can't backtrack.  Hence, any shape with more than 2 such squares (like the T shape) has no solution.

Comment: @Mc add that and some others into your solution and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: It's added, with pictures.

Comment: I tried to edit "inverse" to "converse" but apparently edits must be at least 6 chars

Comment: @Sp3000 nice catch!

Comment: Another heuristic: color the squares like a checkerboard. The number of white and black squares can only differ by 1 if it is solvable. If e.g. there is one more white square than black, then the path must start and end on white.

Comment: @Lopsy I have added your heuristic, good job!