# Can the rook pass every square just once?

Tags: chess, solvability

I had a math teacher in high school who gave us a puzzle to solve. We had to draw a chessboard with one piece that could only move **in straight paths**. Diagonal movement was forbidden. The goal was to draw a path which passed every square on the board **only** once. **The piece had to start at A1 and finish at H8.** Unfortunately he never gave us the answer to the puzzle and I'm getting to the point that I believe the reason for that is because there is no such answer.

What do you guys think? Can this puzzle be solved?

Comment: Only once? Or can it pass through each square more than once? And Welcome to Puzzling!!

Comment: @Sid yes, only once. My bad, should've been more specific.

Comment: Does the path need to be closed; i.e., to return to its starting point?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, not necessarily.

Comment: Are we missing some rule or can't you just move along the board in a zig-zag fashion? Or am I misunderstanding the puzzle?

Comment: Then either I don't understand the task or I don't understand the difficulty. Start at a1, walk to a8, then b8 and back to b1, then c1 and up to c8, etc.

Comment: Actually, even if it needs to be closed you can do the same. a1 to a8 to b8 to b2, c2, c8, d8, d2, e2, e8, f8, f2, g2, g8, h8, h1, back to a1.

Comment: Does "draw a chessboard" mean something more complicated than "visit every square on a chessboard"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm sorry, I gave you the wrong picture. I'll edit the post. Check it out in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Ahhhh, that's quite different.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan apologies for the confusion. So what are your thoughts?

Comment: That question features a knight rather than a king...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oops, sorry about that. I'll delete it

Comment: I do wonder whether the question is meant to be about a knight rather than a king. With a king it still seems too easy.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan WAIT WAIT WAIT. I totally remembered it wrong.

Comment: OK, I'm waiting...

Comment: Of course, this puzzle takes into account the Chess pieces moves? I mean if it's a King it can move diagonally, etc.

Comment: I suspect that both my answer and Marius's will be invalidated by whatever correction is forthcoming...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I remember my teacher being a total a-hole and didn't allow diagonal movement.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan which basically makes the king not a king...

Comment: Then see my recently-updated answer which deals with that case.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this is a duplicate, but I can't find a copy of it right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check to see if a Configuration is Possible: prove there's an Hamiltonian path on a connected subset of the square grid graph](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/check-to-see-if-a-configuration-is-possible-prove-theres-an-hamiltonian-path-o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The task is

> impossible (and would incidentally be likewise impossible with a knight)

because

> the total number of moves has to be 63, and each move changes the colour of the square the piece is on, so the piece must end on a square of colour opposite to the one it started on.

An earlier version of the question didn't have the prohibition on diagonal moves. In that case

> the task is possible

because

> we can use a zig-zagging path made mostly of diagonals, as follows. Start on a1. Move east to b1, and then *northwest to a2*. Move north to a3, and then *southeast to c1*. Move east to d1, and then *northwest to a4*. Keep going in this fashion; you end up on h8 as required.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment, I didn't think it would be relevant anymore. I posted this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479204/knight-on-a-chessboard-moving-from-a1-to-h8

Comment: Hmm makes sense. Conclusion: my teacher was d-ck.