# Find a specific path on an n x n grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Given a puzzle of the following form:

Find a path between the top left corner to the bottom right corner, visiting each spot (.) exactly once. You can only move horizontally or vertically.

```
x  .  .

.  .  .

.  .  x
```

For a 3 x 3 grid, this yields two solutions:

```
x--.--.
      |
.--.--.
|
.--.--x

x  .--.
|  |  |
.  .  .
|  |  |
.--.  x
```

There are mul olutions for a 5x5 grid, 7x7, and so on.

But for a 2x2, 4x4, 6x6, and higher n x n (where n is even), this does not seem to yield any solution.

How would you prove that this is the case? That there is no solution for n x n grids where n is even? (Is this even true?)

Comment: This feels like a duplicate question.

Comment: Upon further investigation this question is a subquestion of : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/check-to-see-if-a-configuration-is-possible-prove-theres-an-hamiltonian-path-o/6103#6103, however @JonMark Perry has a good explanation in his answer below for why the checkerboard test works.

Comment: More specific duplicate might be [Can the rook pass every square just once?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46051/can-the-rook-pass-every-square-just-once)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Imagine the grid as a chessboard. Then for a $2k\times2k$ board, the two corners are the same colour, say white. Any path must travel $WBWB\dots WBW$, which is always an odd number of moves, however we need to travel through an even number of squares, so the task is impossible.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this idea to non-grid graphs? A general heuristic that relates graph-coloring to the *non-existence* of a Hamiltonian path? (this is knowing that determining the *existence* of a Hamiltonian path is NP-Complete)

Comment: I have a feeling something along the lines of: if a graph can be 2-colored and the number of vertices of one color is equal to the number of vertices of the other color -> there cannot exist a Hamiltonian path. Does that sound about right?

Comment: well the simplest tree graphs disprove that

Comment: Right. Heck a simple line disproves that. Then what is it about a grid/lattice shape that makes this checkerboard heuristic work? Is there a characteristic that you can extend to more general graphs?

Comment: I think you might need another constraint in that you might wish to specify required start and end points to check for the existence of an HP between them.

Comment: That makes sense as, for example, in any even grid you can always find a path that visits all points and end up at the starting point, but can't do that for any odd grid.

Comment: I think I got it- for any graph that can be two coloured, if there is an even number of vertices and you start and end on the same color, there is no HP possible (by the explanation given above). Similarly if your two coloured graph has an odd number of vertices, and you start and end on different colours, there’s also no HP possible. The idea is that any traversal has to flip between colours and if you end on different colours you’ll have taken even number of steps- a contradiction if there’s an odd number of nodes total.